# Set a ImageSource from FileSystem in Metro app

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

In the ApplicationData.Current.RomanigFolder, I save an jpg file. It is possible to read the content of this file in a stream or MemoryStream and set it to the ImageSource?

I use it in a WPF-Application with .NET 4.0 with follwing code: (img is a XAML-Image-Control

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data.message.imageUrl);
bi.StreamSource = sr.BaseStream;
bi.EndInit();
img.Source = bi;
sr.Close();
```

For a Metro app I see no way to set a StreamSource to an BitmapImage. How can I set a Image-File to an Image-Control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For writing “Metro Style Apps”, or apps built for Windows 8, to set the source of an image in WPF project.

Here’s the code:

```
// Usage
myImage.Source = ImageFromRelativePath(this, "relative_path_to_file_make_sure_build_set_to_content");

public static BitmapImage ImageFromRelativePath(FrameworkElement parent, string path)
{
    var uri = new Uri(parent.BaseUri, path);
    BitmapImage result = new BitmapImage();
    result.UriSource = uri;
    return result;
}
```

Reference: http://www.codingbeta.com/programatically-setting-image-source-in-metro-style-apps-with-wpf/

Comment: Is there a way to control when the file is loaded into memory? (Like BitmapCacheOption gives us in WPF)